# Convert characters in a string

Tags: string, perl

I have a string like:

```
Why RUNAS Windows \xee\x80\x80\x45xplorer\xee\x80\x81 Doesn\xe2\x80\x99t 
Work After Installing IE7 St\xc3\xa5le
```

which I get by reading an XML file. This is a UTF-8 String. Now I want to print its equivalent unicode characters so that I get:

```
Why RUNAS Windows Explorer Doesn’t Work After Installing IE7 Ståle
```

I tried a small program:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use Encode;

my $str = "Why RUNAS Windows \xee\x80\x80\x45xplorer\xee\x80\x81 Doesn\xe2\x80\x99t Work After Installing IE7 St\xc3\xa5le";
print $str;
```

And it worked!!

The problem is when I'm trying to read the string from a file, it is not converting. So the following does not produce the unicode output:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use Encode;
my $str = <DATA>;
$str = decode("utf8", $str);
open OUT, ">", "o.txt" or die;
binmode(OUT,":utf8");
print OUT $str;
__DATA__
Why RUNAS Windows \xee\x80\x80\x45xplorer\xee\x80\x81 Doesn\xe2\x80\x99t Work After Installing IE7 St\xc3\xa5le
```

Comment: You pour soul you.  Whoever decided that your XML format needed to encode the UTF characters as pseudo-escaped ASCII needs to repent.

Comment: HI @RobertP: Any idea how to get this working ?

Comment: Note the "Wide character" warnings you get (if you used `use warnings;` as you should). You forgot to encode your output. To fix that bug, add `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` (or whatever encoding your terminal expects).

Answer (score 6):

The difference between your two examples is that the backslashes in the first example are being interpolated as bytes as it's compiled, whereas in the second example, they're literal text.  You're reading in a sequence of characters "\", "x", "e", "e" in the second example, but the first turns it into a single unicode character in memory.

If the XML file contains unicode characters, Perl can read them in just fine; they don't need to be escaped like shown.

If you have to keep those unicode characters as sequences of characters, consider using a library from CPAN to decode them.  At a glance, it looks like [Encode::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3a%3aEscape) would meet your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode::Escape;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print decode 'unicode-escape', $_; # convert byte references to (utf-8) bytes
}

__DATA__
Why RUNAS Windows \xee\x80\x80\x45xplorer\xee\x80\x81 Doesn\xe2\x80\x99t
Work After Installing IE7 St\xc3\xa5le
```

There may be others.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty obvious:

```
print "abc\n";   # Prints <abc>

<DATA>;          # Doesn't print <abc>
__DATA__
print "abc\n";
```

So this should be no surprise:

```
"\x61";          # Evaluates to string <a>

<DATA>;          # Doesn't evaluate to string <a>
__DATA__
"\x61"
```

You're confusing string literals (a Perl operator) and strings (sequences of characters). `readline` doesn't execute your data files as Perl code. (Even if it did, you were missing the quotes.) If you want to transform strings you read, you're going to have to tell Perl to transform them.

```
s/ \\x(..) | \\([^a-zA-Z]) | \\(.) /
   defined($1) ? chr(hex($1)) :
   defined($2) ? $2 :
   do { warn "Unknown escape \\$3\n"; "\\$3" }
/sexg;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use substitution with evaluation to change each code to the corresponding byte. No `use utf8` nor `use Encode` is needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = <DATA>;
$str =~ s/\\x(..)/chr hex $1/eg;
open my $OUT, '>', 'o.txt' or die $!; # No binmode utf8 - byte semantics needed!
print $OUT $str;

__DATA__
Why RUNAS Windows \xee\x80\x80\x45xplorer\xee\x80\x81 Doesn\xe2\x80\x99t Work After Installing IE7 St\xc3\xa5le
```

Comment: This won't work quite right.  The escapes he's showing are multi-byte unicode characters, so turning them into single byte characters would give the wrong character.